# ForeColor with codes color

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created dynamically `HyperLink`. And I want to change the color by adding a color code.

```
HyperLink hpl = new HyperLink();
hpl.Text = "SomeText";
hpl.ForeColor = "#5BB1E6";

//Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Drawing.Color
```

But I can't.

How to add codes color to `ForeColor` ?

Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe you need [`ColorTranslator.FromHtml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromhtml.aspx)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the following code

```
HyperLink hpl = new HyperLink();
hpl.Text = "SomeText";
hpl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#5BB1E6");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
hpl.ForeColor =System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#5BB1E6");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code, it may help you

```
HyperLink hpl = new HyperLink();
hpl.Text = "SomeText";
//use this
hpl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#5BB1E6")
```

hope it helps